# Does strict monotonicity imply image variable is dependent with domain variable?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, independence, measure-theory

Suppose a random variable $X$ and a [strictly monotone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function) (and [measurable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurable_function)) [function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)) $f$ in which $f(X)$ is always defined.

Does it necessarily hold that $f(X)$ is [statistically dependent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)#Independent_%CF%83-algebras) with X?

---

I should emphasize that the random variable is not necessarily equipped with addition, or multiplication, but can be considered an [$(E, \mathcal{E})$-valued random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Measure-theoretic_definition). The strict monotonicity $u < v \implies f(u) < f(v)$ is from a perspective of [order theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function#In_order_theory) where an arbitrary partial order $\leq$ is assumed over the domain/range of $f$. Assume the domain and range of $f$ are the same set.

Comment: What happens when $f$ is constant on the support of $X$? That extreme and degenerate case provides essential insight I believe.

Comment: @whuber OP clearly stated that $f$ is "strictly" monotone.

Comment: @Zhanxiong *Exactly.*  That's the entire point!

Comment: @whuber If $f$ were constant on the support of $X$, then $f(X)$ and $X$ would be independent. I thought about the contrapositive of this and didn't get anywhere. Is the converse true? If the converse is true, then that would answer my question.

Comment: The edit leaves some things to be assumed. What is the partial order on $E$?  Any partial order at all?  What is the range of $f$?  Any set with a partial order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No -- there are simple counterexamples.

I take it that $X:(\Omega,\mathfrak F, \mathbb P)\to (E,\mathcal E)$ is a (generalized) random variable, that $E$ is endowed with a partial order $\le,$ and that $f:(E,\le)\to(E,\le)$ is strictly monotone.

As an example, let $\Omega = \{a,b\},$ $\mathfrak F=\mathcal P(\Omega) = \{\emptyset, \{a\},\{b\},\Omega\}$ is the discrete algebra, and $\mathbb P(\{a\})=1/2$ determines the uniform probability distribution.  Let $E = \mathcal P(\{0,1\}) = \{\emptyset, \{0\}, \{1\}, \{0,1\}\}$ and let $\le = \subseteq$ be the subset relation.  In this partial order $\{0\}$ and $\{1\}$ are *incomparable:* neither is a subset of the other.

Let the random variable $X:\Omega\to E$ be given by

$$X(a)=\{0\},\ X(b) = \{1\}.$$

The sigma-algebra $\sigma(X)$ is $\mathfrak F$ itself.

*We only need to define $f$ on the image of $X.$* (But see the remarks below for why even this is not necessary to make the counterexample work.) To this end, let $f:E\to E$ be the *constant* function $f(y)=\{0,1\}.$  It is *vacuously* strictly monotone, because there are no strict inequalities to check (due to the incomparability of all the elements of $X(\Omega)$).

Define the random variable $Y = f\circ X.$  It is constant,  making it trivial to check the independence of $(X,Y).$

Thus, although neither $X$ nor $f$ are constant, all the conditions hold yet $X$ and $f\circ X$ are independent.

---

If you intended $f$ to be defined on **all** of $E$ and to be strictly monotone there, simply extend this example. For instance, let $E$ be the integers with $0$ doubled:  $$E = \{(n,i)\in \mathbb Z\times \{0,1\} \mid n\ne 0 \implies i=0\}.$$

The usual order $\le$ on $\mathbb Z$ induces an order on $E.$ We use the usual order on the first components but we make $(0,0)$ and $(0,1)$ incomparable.  This extends the previous example, which is isomorphic to the order on $\{(-1,0),(0,0),(0,1),(1,0)\}.$  The pairs $(0,0)$ and $(0,1)$ play the roles of $\{0\}$ and $\{1\}.$  Define $f$ as

$$f((n,i)) = (n+1,0)$$

for all $n\in\mathbb Z$ and $i\in\{0,1\}.$

Answer (score 2):

Your idea of using proof by contrapositive is correct (I assume $X$ is non-degenerate, otherwise for any $f$, $X$ and $f(X)$ are trivially independent).  The key argument appears in proving Kolmogorov's $0$-$1$ law as well.

Suppose $X$ and $f(X)$ are independent, then as a measurable function of $X$, $f(X)$ and $f(X)$ would be independent, which implies that
\begin{align}
E[f(X)^2] = E[f(X) \cdot f(X)] = E[f(X)]E[f(X)]. 
\end{align}
But this would be equivalent to say $\operatorname{Var}(f(X)) = 0$, hence $Y := f(X)$ is degenerate.  Because $f$ is strictly monotone, $X = f^{-1}(Y)$ is well defined and must be degenerate as well, which contradicts with that $X$ is non-degenerate.  This proves your conjecture.

Comment: Your answer covers a strong majority of cases (+1), and it made me realize I made a mistake in communication. Implicit in my question is the possibility of random variables that are not equipped with scalar/vector/matrix addition. A lot of statistics doesn't involve such variables, of course, but I deal with them often. My apologies if I ignored a social norm. I'll update my question.